# How to import PsiClass for Intellij plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to create a plugin for intellij but am having trouble accessing PsiClass.

When i try to `import com.intellij.psi.PsiClass;`, it cant resolve the symbol.

The solution [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/platform/2019/06/java-functionality-extracted-as-a-plugin/) doesnt work for me as it refers to build.gradle but i only have build.gradle.kts in my plugin project.

Also adding `<depends>com.intellij.modules.java</depends>` to the plugin.xml file gives a cannot resolve error.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72568509/how-can-i-apply-a-plugin-to-itself-using-kotlin-dsl might help.

Comment: I'd recommend you raise this issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development to discuss it with the IDEA team directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In build.gradle.kts, under the `intellij{}` block, add "java" to the `plugins.set(listOf(/* Plugin Dependencies */))`.

Mine looks like this:

```
// Configure Gradle IntelliJ Plugin
// Read more: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/tools-gradle-intellij-plugin.html
intellij {
    version.set("2022.1.4")
    type.set("IC") // Target IDE Platform

    plugins.set(listOf(/* Plugin Dependencies */"java"))
}
```

Also in plugin.xml, under the default `<depends>com.intellij.modules.platform</depends>` line, add another line `<depends>com.intellij.java</depends>`.

I already had these lines added but they didnt work, but after reopening the project a few hours later it worked, so perhaps rebuilding the project will fix the issue after adding these lines.